# Why does json.Encoder add an extra line?

Tags: json, go

[`json.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewEncoder) seems to behave slightly different than `json.Marshal`. Specifically it adds a new line at the end of the encoded value. Any idea why is that? It looks like a bug to me.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"
import "bytes"

func main() {
    var v string
    v = "hello"
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    json.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(v)
    b, _ := json.Marshal(&v)

    fmt.Printf("%q, %q", buf.Bytes(), b)
}
```

This outputs

```
"\"hello\"\n", "\"hello\""
```

[<kbd>Try it in the Playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/r0Hwtnd03j)

Comment: It uses the newline to delimit multiple objects. Marshal only encodes a single object

Comment: Right! That's the answer!

Comment: it dosn't use it to delimit multiple object as you can set something like `encoder.SetIndent("", "  ")` and you get new lines all over the place..

Answer (score 15):

Because they explicitly added a new line character when using `Encoder.Encode`.  Here's the source code to that func, and it actually states it adds a newline character in the documentation (see comment, which is the documentation):

https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/stream.go?s=4272:4319

```
// Encode writes the JSON encoding of v to the stream,
// followed by a newline character.
//
// See the documentation for Marshal for details about the
// conversion of Go values to JSON.
func (enc *Encoder) Encode(v interface{}) error {
    if enc.err != nil {
        return enc.err
    }
    e := newEncodeState()
    err := e.marshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    // Terminate each value with a newline.
    // This makes the output look a little nicer
    // when debugging, and some kind of space
    // is required if the encoded value was a number,
    // so that the reader knows there aren't more
    // digits coming.
    e.WriteByte('\n')

    if _, err = enc.w.Write(e.Bytes()); err != nil {
        enc.err = err
    }
    encodeStatePool.Put(e)
    return err
}
```

Now, why did the Go developers do it other than "makes the output look a little nice"?  One answer:

#### Streaming

The go json `Encoder` is optimized for streaming (e.g. MB/GB/PB of json data).  It is typical that when streaming you need a way to deliminate when your stream has completed.  In the case of `Encoder.Encode()`, that is a `\n` newline character.  Sure, you can certainly write to a buffer.  But you can also write to an io.Writer which would stream the block of `v`.

This is opposed to the use of `json.Marshal` which is generally discouraged if your input is from an untrusted (and unknown limited) source (e.g. an ajax POST method to your web service - what if someone posts a 100MB json file?).  And, `json.Marshal` would be a final complete set of json - e.g. you wouldn't expect to concatenate a few 100 `Marshal` entries together.  You'd use Encoder.Encode() for that to build a large set and write to the buffer, stream, file, io.Writer, etc.

Whenever in doubt if it's a bug, I always lookup the source - that's one of the advantages to Go, it's source and compiler is just pure Go.  Within [n]vim I use `\gb` to open the source definition in a browser with [my `.vimrc` settings](https://github.com/eduncan911/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc).

Comment: Isn't the usual way of delimiting the stream to return `io.EOF` as error? Using `\n` doesn't seem to be useful here.

Comment: `io.EOF` typically indicates the end of all data, that nothing else is ever going to be sent.

Comment: This isn't true for the gzipWriter however; it sends io.EOF whenever you flush.

Comment: Well, you can still keep Reading from the gzip stream though even through a Flush.

Answer (score 1):

You can erease the newline by backward stream:

```
f, _ := os.OpenFile(fname, ...)
encoder := json.NewEncoder(f)
encoder.Encode(v)
f.Seek(-1, 1)
f.WriteString("other data ...")
```

They should let user control this strange behavior:

- a build option to disable it
- Encoder.SetEOF(eof string)
- Encoder.SetIndent(prefix, indent, eof string)

Answer (score 0):

The [Encoder](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Encoder) writes a stream of documents. The extra whitespace terminates a JSON document in the stream.

A terminator is required for stream readers.   Consider a stream containing these JSON documents: `1`, `2`, `3`.   Without the extra whitespace, the data on the wire is the sequence of bytes `123`.  This is a single JSON document with the number 123, not three documents.